# How to use Typescript without framework?

Tags: typescript

I would like to use Typescript instead of Object Oriented Javascript + Ecmascript in the conventional frontend.

What is the correct way to compile typescript for ecmascript, without there being any compatibility or error issues with @imports?

NOTE: I do not use the webpack, as I'm not doing SPA's, so I'd like the specific @import for each component on specific pages (.html).

Comment: TypeScript alone without framework is javascript though.

Comment: Yes, but it gives @imports errors, when it is not used with already preconfigured frameworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [`typescript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) npm package. It contains the tsc command to compile typescript to javascript. you can ether install it globaly or add it as a dev dependency to your project.

**Globaly:**

`npm install -g typescript`

`tsc index.ts`

**Development Dependency:**

`npm install --save-dev typescript`

`node node_modules/bin/tsc.js index.ts`

Instead of supplying an input file you can also configure the build using a [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) in your current directory.

Comment: Qual configuração no tsconfig.json eu utilizo para não dar problemas de @import no browserw